# How to define a function in python that takes a file in a current directory and returns a dictionary?

Tags: python

The instructions I am asked to follow:

Define a function `make_length_wordcount()` that:

1. Takes as input, the filename in the current directory (as a string)
2. Returns a dictionary, which each key is word length and its value is the number of words with that length.

For example, if the input file’s text is `“Hello Python people  Welcome to the world of Python”`, then the dictionary should
be:
`{2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1}`

The code below is what I have so far.

```
def make_length_wordcount(filename):
    
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    words = content.split()
    
    counter = {}
    
    for word in words:
        if len(word) in counter:
            counter[len(item)] += 1
        else:
            counter[len(item)] = 1
    
    return counter

def make_length_wordcount('nasdaq.txt'):
```

Although it runs, when I try and test the function against the .txt files that we have, I get the following error:

```
File "/var/folders/n0/lxhk5ms10qj_9m99p7th0jjr0000gn/T/ipykernel_54104/3868574578.py", line 21
    def make_length_wordcount('nasdaq.txt'):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of text. Include the actual text in your question instead. Please refer to [formatting help](/help/formatting) if you need to. Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] that _actually reproduces your problem_.

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? Please post that information as well

Comment: Did you mean `if len(word) in counter`?

Comment: You just have a number of typos. When you fix them the program seems ok.

Comment: @quamrana, updated with the corrections I found in my original code.

Comment: Yes, that's one of them. You need to review how to call functions in python. I upvoted your question because you have made a sincere effort to update the question in response to comments.

Comment: @Wondercricket added the error message at the bottom of my question, thanks!

Comment: You should call the function like this `result = make_length_wordcount('nasdaq.txt')` and print the result to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def make_length_wordcount(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = infile.read()
    words = content.split()
    counter = {}
    for i in words:
        key_len = len(i)
        if key_len in counter:
            new_val = counter[key_len] + 1
            counter[key_len] = new_val
        else:
            counter[key_len] = 1
    return counter
```

UPDATE: Seems like you have changed the requirement

To call this function, just do

```
make_length_wordcount('Hello.txt')
```

output

```
{5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

Comment: To complete this answer you need to show how to call this function. btw How did you manage to post this answer? The question was closed about 5 minutes before you posted.

Comment: @quamrana Not sure. May be I was still working on my solution when you closed it and it just let me work on it.

Comment: Ok, I usually get chucked out posting my answer when a question gets closed. Still +1 for a good answer. btw it might be slightly better to use `with open(...`